# Найти количество элементов массива, меньших заданного числа В, и произведение четных элементов

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c++14

Есть код который считает произвидение выше указаного пользователем b (то есть числа ниже b игнорируются), нужно чтобы только четные числа перемножались, которые соответственно выше b. Затем вывести количество этих самых четных.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    float b;
    cout << "Число b: ";
    cin >> b;

    int n;
    cout << "Кол-во элементов n: ";
    cin >> n;

    float* a = new float[n];

    float result = 1;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "a[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> a[i];
        if (a[i] > b && a[i %2])
        {
            result *= a[i];
            count++;
        }
    }

    if (count == 0)
        result = 0;

    cout << result << endl;

    delete[] a;

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `if (a[i] > b && a[i %2])
  {
   result *= a[i];
   count++;
  }`

В этом блоке кода я пытался высчитать парное число но оно не работает(

Comment: Если нужны **четные числа**, то это такие, что `a[i] % 2 == 0`, а не `a[i % 2]` (тут вы смотрите, не равно ли нулю `a[0]` (для всех *четных i*) или `a[1]` (для *нечетных i`*))

Comment: Верно, заглупил. Работает, спасибо, осталось вывести их количество.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем ничего сложного просто запутался немного, решил в итоге.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <locale.h> /* Для русского языка */

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
        float b;
        cout << "Число b: ";
        cin >> b;

        int n;
        cout << "Кол-во элементов n: ";
        cin >> n;

        int* a = new int[n];

        float result = 1;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i(0); i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << "a[" << i << "] = ";
            cin >> a[i];
            if (a[i] > b && a[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                result *= a[i];
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == 0)
            result = 0;

        cout <<"Произвидение чисел: " << result << endl << "Количество парных чисел выше "<<b<< " :" << count << endl;

        delete[] a;

    }
```